# Focus Error on "Other" flag fields

Tags: bug, status-norepro, flags

Using Google Chrome Version 30.0.1581.2 dev on OSX Mavericks, I've found an issue where I can't type a custom message for flagging a question.

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Click flag on a question
2. Click "Other, needs moderator attention"
3. Click to focus on the text box used for inputting extra information and type something

**Expected Results**

1. Focus is shifted to the input box and a reason for flagging can by typed.

**Actual Results**

1. Focus is shifted to the text field, but is shifted back to the "Other" Radio button almost immediately.

**Other Information**

1. Tabbing to the next field works as expect, indicating it's the click event being handled by both inputs.
2. Repeatable on Safari 7.0 (9537.71) OSX Mavericks

Comment: I am using Safari on Mavericks but cannot reproduce the issue. You normally don't have to click the text box to change focus. Clicking "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" automatically switches the focus to the text box.

Comment: Dev versions [are not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/152859) and might break unexpectedly. Switch to stable Chrome release and all should work as expected.

Comment: Well, @Antony is using the same browser and couldn't reproduce, you probably have dev version of that as well.

Comment: It seems I didn't finish that last comment :P It was reproducible on Safari, non-dev version

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Safari 7.0 is the current version of Safari; not a dev version.

Comment: James and @Martijn OK, but I count on the dev who marked it norepro that he also checked with Safari 7 and couldn't reproduce so might be local problem.

Comment: @Sha: fair enough; I see someone else was not able to repro this in Safari 7 either.